# Best practices when accessing the attributes and methods of other classes

Tags: python, inheritance

this is a best practices type of question. I want to access the attributes and methods of one class from another(maybe this is a bad practice in itself) and what i'm doing to achieve this is

```
class table():
    def __init__(self):
        self.color = 'green'
    colora = 'red' 

    def showColor(self):
        print('The variable inside __init__ is called color with a value of '+self.color)
        print('The variable outside all methos called colora has a value of '+colora)

class pencil(table):
    def __init__(self):
        print('i can access the variable colora from the class wtf its value is '+table.colora)
        print('But i cant access the variable self.color inside __init__ using table.color ')

object = pencil()
>>>
i can access the variable colora from the class wtf its value is red
But i can't access the variable self.color inside __init__ using table.color 
>>>
```

As you can see i'm making an instance of the class pencil and as its defined in the class i'm using the notation to inherit from one class to another.

I've read everywhere people declaring their classes attributes inside **init** does that mean that i shouldnt be accessing other classes without using instances of it? 
I think this is a problem of inheritance but i can't get the concept into my head, and i've read a few explanations in books and tutorials.

In the end i just want to be able to access the attributes and methods of one class with another.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

more explixitly, if you want to access table.color from pencil, you don't need to wrap it in a method, but you need to call the table constructor first:

```
class table():

    colora = 'red'
    def __init__(self):
        self.color = 'green'
        print 'table: table.color', self.color
        print 'table: table.color', table.colora

class pencil(table):

    def __init__(self):
        table.__init__(self)
        print 'pencil: table.colora', table.colora
        print 'pencil: pencil.color',  self.color
        print 'pencil: pencil.colora', pencil.colora

obj = pencil()
```

Another unrelated issue, this line

object = pencil()

is hiding the python "object" symbol, most likely not a good idea.

Comment: Oh i see, the tutorials i saw had the inheritance with more complicated examples that was confusing, but basically all i need is to pass the parent in parentheses and then call the parent's __init__ and then i will be able to access all its attributes defined in __init__ and of course its methods and of course its "public" attributes suchs as the ones outside a any of the class methods.
Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, kind of, but all attributes are "public", see http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables. The "passing the parent" indicates that you are inheriting from it, and the constructor call ensures you get access to the attributes via self.attrubute_name. If you don't call the constructor, you would still have access to the "colora" attribute, but not self.color.

Answer (score 1):

Attributes bound to `self` within a normal method are only accessible via the instance that was passed as `self` when the method was called. If the method is never called via an instance then the attribute doesn't exist.

Class attributes are different in that they're bound when the class itself is created.

Also, if an attribute starts with a single underscore (`_`) then never access it outside the class at all if it can be helped.

Comment: oh, ok so, all the attributes i want to be accesed from outside the class i need to first "publish" them calling a method that returns them right?

Comment: Isn't `_` used to mean that it won't be imported when doing `from module import *`?

Comment: @Guillermo: "creates them" is a more accurate way of looking at it.

Comment: @A: That is one of the implications, yes.